# yaml scientific notation syntax

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp, snakeyaml

While working with a yaml document, I found that one of my values was getting parsed as a string with snakeyaml:

-8e-05

I found that ros, which uses yaml-cpp to write yamls is using the following code to write an array

```
out << YAML::BeginSeq;
for (int i = 0; i < m.rows*m.cols; ++i)
  out << m.data[i];
out << YAML::EndSeq;
```

but the c++ code above (copied from ros "parse_yml.cpp" in the camera_calibration package) creates -8e-05 while snakeyaml parses it as a string.

So who's right, should there be a bug report? if so to who? The 1.2 yaml specification seems to allow for optional decimal, but I couldn't figure out if the 1.1 yaml spec allows it which snakeyaml implements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output should be parsed as `!!float` according to YAML 1.2, but originally was `!!str` in YAML 1.1; as @psr says, this is to match the JSON spec.

The YAML 1.2 spec gives a [JSON schema](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2804356) and an extension, the ["core schema"](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071). In both cases, the `!!float` regular expression is:

```
[-+]? ( \. [0-9]+ | [0-9]+ ( \. [0-9]* )? ) ( [eE] [-+]? [0-9]+ )?
```

which allows for an optional decimal. (The core schema adds support for infinity and not-a-number.)

The YAML 1.1 spec didn't specify this type of tag resolution directly, but it gave several related pages for each type. The [`!!float` page](http://yaml.org/type/float.html) lists the regular expression:

```
[-+]?([0-9][0-9_]*)?\.[0-9.]*([eE][-+][0-9]+)?
```

(as well as versions for base-60, infinity, and not-a-number).
 This appears to require the decimal.

This has been fixed in SnakeYAML (see http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/issues/detail?id=130), as of version 1.9.

Comment: Thank you Jesse, This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to work around this fairly easily by modifying the output of the snakeyaml since I know more about the datatypes, but thought I'd try to help out if I could. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: The issue has been fixed in SnakeYAML: http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/issues/detail?id=130

Answer (score 0):

YAML is a superset of JSON, and if you look at http://www.json.org/ it has a BNF-equivalent diagram at the bottom of the page which shows the definition of how to parse a number.   -8e-05 fits that definition, so snakeyami is not correct parsing it as a string.